# Ubuntu 21.10 shuts down when lid is closed - how to identify hardware problem?

Tags: drivers, suspend, nvidia-geforce, amd-processor

this is my first askubuntu post so please tell me if I forget anything important.

I have a Asus ROG zephyrus G14 (AMD Ryzen 9 5800HS processor & Nvidia 3060 GPU) that I'm dual booting Ubuntu 21.10/windows 10.

under Ubuntu, if I close the lid the computer usually shuts down. A couple of times it didn't but the keyboard didn't light up and flashed regularly, and the only way to solve it was to reboot. On one occasion I shut the lid, cycled home and by the time I got there it was overheating.

from what I understand from ubuntu website it's probably a hardware compatibility problem.

I want the computer to go to sleep when I shut the lid rather than shut down

**How can I identify what the hardware problem is and how to solve it ?**

For now I've tried going in "software and updates", "additional driver" and switched the GPU driver from "X.org X server" to the proprietary "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia driver 470" (which has only resulted in loss of three finger swiping functionality).
I have the option "[...] from nvidia driver 495", and "server Drivers from" driver-460-server or driver-470-server.

thanks for your help !

Comment: So, to clarify, you *want* the computer to automatically suspend when you close the lid, yes? (Many people ask about the opposite, which is why I'm asking)

Comment: yes that's it !

Comment: Is the machine able to suspend properly when you use the "Power Off / Log out" ⇢ Suspend menu options? (Upper-right corner of the screen)

Comment: no, while suspended and after, the keyboard doesn't light up and the keys flash twice rapidly, every three seconds it's very regular) and luminosity went to 0.
Also I tried rebooting it by typing "reboot" in terminal and it wouldn't shut down, I stayed on a black screen with a text cursor in the top left and had to press the power button, first time this happens...

Comment: Note the time you close the lid, and the time you reopen. Write them down. When you have a working system, check your logs for both of those times.

Comment: @user535733 what logs ? (I'm new to linux ^^)

Comment: Get into the habit of using the Search box at the top of every AskUbuntu page. Try there first for common *how do I find XYZ* or *how do I do ABC* questions. You will get faster answers.

Comment: so sorry for answer time I didn't see your answer
I get [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] ERROR [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] so I' guessing there's a problem with the nvidia driver, I'll look into that and edit if I can fix it